# regarding file existence check within a for loop in C++

Tags: c++, file

I am attempting to check if a file exists, and then if so proceed with a task and if not to just output that there is no such file.  I have done this in other code but it doesn't seem to be working with my current code.

The basics of it read:

```
count=argc;


for(i=0; i < count-1; i++)
{
    filename[i] = argv[i+1];
}


for( i=0; i < count-1; i++)
      {
      int tempi=i;
      ifstream infile(filename[i].c_str());

           if(infile)
           {
           //do things
           }
           else
           {
           cout<<"no file"<<endl;
           }
```

Comment: Which part doesn't seem to be working? What does "seem to be working" mean in this case? What did you expect to happen, and what happened instead?

Comment: What on earth does "doesn't seem to be working" mean? Argh!

Comment: I'd really suggest to make a `stat` call ([win32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14h5k7ff(v=vs.80).aspx) or [UNIX](http://fuse4bsd.creo.hu/localcgi/man-cgi.cgi?stat+2))

Comment: Don't use `stat()` if you want to know if a file exists on Unix, use `access()` instead.  It's cheaper.

Comment: @John: thanks, learning everyday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `infile.is_open()`.   Also, do you plan to do something with the file if it exists, or not?

Comment: mmmm I'd really need to go and check. I didn't think that was true.

Comment: @sehe: I had a typo in my answer at first.  Probably you saw it when it said `.open()` rather than `.is_open()`.

Comment: unapersson is correct. [Testing the stream state is sufficient.](http://ideone.com/60Km5)

Comment: Well isn't that amazing.  I retract my answer, and truly hope @Sam will let us know what the solution to his problem really was, since it should not be mine.  Unfortunately I cannot delete this answer since it has been accepted; perhaps the accepted answer will change (and should).

Comment: Hey everyone, sorry I didn't respond sooner.  I was actually correct in my original idea.  I had just misplaced a curly brace or two which threw it off.  The problem was that it would freeze if I had entered an incorrect file name.  Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

The canonical way to access argv is:

```
int main( int argc, char * argv[] ) {
    for ( int i = 1; i < argc; i++ ) {
        // do something with argv[i]
    }
}
```

Comment: But this does not answer the question.

Comment: That's no reason to post a comment as an answer. Please read our FAQ.

Comment: @Tomalak I've been posting here in one guise or another for several years. Believe me, I know how the site works. And if you want to post code, the only realistic way to  do it is via an answer.

Comment: That still doesn't make this an answer. Starting to see why you might have felt the need to change your identity over the years.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>`infile`, in the conditional, evaluates to `false` when the stream is in a "bad" state.</strike>

<strike>However, merely failing to open a file does not leave the stream in a bad state (welcome to C++!). Only after attempting to read from the stream would this mechanism work for you.</strike>

<strike>Fortunately, you can use `infile.is_open()` to explicitly test for whether the stream was opened or not.</strike>

**Edit**

The above is *not true*.

[Testing the stream state is sufficient](http://ideone.com/60Km5), and I can't see anything wrong with your code.